# Prove that there are open set $U$ and $V$ in $X$ such that $x∈U, y∈V$ and $U∩V=∅$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X,D$ be a metric space. Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are two distinct points of $X$. Prove that there are open set $U$ and $V$ in $X$ such that $x∈U, y∈V$ and $U∩V=∅$

My professor gave me a hint that I should let $U=N\bigl(x,\frac 1 2 D(x,y)\bigr)$. Is this mean $\epsilon=\frac 1 2 D(x,y)$ and I should prove that $N_\epsilon x$ is subset of $U$? How can I do that ?

For $V$ should I let $V=N\bigl(y,\frac 1 2 D(x,y)\bigr)$ and do the same?

This is what I understand:

Let $U=N\bigl(x,\frac 1 2 D(x,y)\bigr)$ and $\epsilon= \frac 1 2 \min\bigl(x,\frac 1 2 D(x,y)\bigr)$ so $N_\epsilon (x)$ is subset of $N\bigl(x,\frac 1 2 D(x,y)\bigr)$ thus $N_\epsilon (x)$ is subset of $U$. Hence $U$ is open.

is this correct? do I need to add something?

Comment: $U$ *is* $N_\epsilon x$ (if I understand your notation correctly). Simply: let $\epsilon$ be half the distance from $x$ to $y$. Let $U$ be the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ with center $x$ and let $V$ be the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ with center $y$. Show $U$ and $V$ satisfy what they are supposed to satisfy.

Comment: Also note that you are trying to show that every metric space is a *Hausdorff space*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let U=N(x,(1/2)D(x,y)) and V=N(y,(1/2)D(x,y)) to prove that  U∩V=∅
using triangular inequality let x' ∈ U
then D(x,x')+D(y,x')>=D(x,y)
since  D(x,x')<=ϵ/2
D(y,x')>=D(x,y)-ϵ/2
which implies D(y,x')>ϵ/2 therefore x'is not an element of V , therefore  U∩V=∅

This is an exercise problem in Foundations of Topology by C Wayne

Comment: $(\forall \text{intro topology texts})(\text{this is proved in the text} \lor \text {this is an exercise})$

Answer (score 1):

The hint says what it says: let $U=N(x,\frac{1}{2}D(x,y))$ and let $V=N(y,\frac{1}{2}D(x,y))$. If $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}D(x,y)$ then $U=N(x,\epsilon), V=N(y,\epsilon)$. It's easy to see that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$, so now you need to show that $U\cap V=\emptyset$. Recall that if there exists a $z\in U\cap V$, then by the definition of $U$ and $V$, we must have $d(x,z)<\epsilon$ and $d(y,z)<\epsilon$. Can you see how this leads to a contradiction (think triangles)? It would then follow that no such $z$ exists and so $U\cap V=\emptyset$.